# Unable set Authorization Bearer token in Request Header for all rest call using Spring boot code after user login from Azure AD SSO login

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security, azure-active-directory

After user SSO login into app Id_token (Authorization bearer) value required in all request header for all rest call, but currently its not coming in header.If there any way to get authorization bearer token and set in all request header.With below login request with response_type as id_token, getting id_token in payload, but required id_token in all request header,

```
    https://login.microsoftonline.com/<TenantId>/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?
    client_id=<ClientId>
    &response_type=id_token
    &redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A3000%2Fdashboard%2F
    &response_mode=form_post
    &scope=openid
    &state=12345
    &nonce=678910
```

Comment: You have to provide more information, for example your spring security configuration, your preferred authorization flow, .... . By default, you log in once in your authorization server (Azure) and spring creates a session (-cookie) and the authorization is handled internally by the session cookie without using the authorization server. You can configure different ways of authorization (e.g. JWT) but you should decide which pattern fits your requirements best.

Comment: I have to go with JWT authorization, where JWT Authorization barer token will set in all rest call in controller automatically, one user login into application.

Comment: With below login request with response_type as id_token, getting id_token in payload, but required id_token in all request header,

https://login.microsoftonline.com/<TenantId>/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?
client_id=<ClientId>
&response_type=id_token
&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A3000%2Fdashboard%2F
&response_mode=form_post
&scope=openid
&state=12345
&nonce=678910

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below code to set Authorization Bearer token in Request Header for rest call using Spring boot code.

**My Controller:**

```java
@GetMapping(value = "/getmanagementgroup")
    public static String getManagementGroup() throws Exception {
        String access_token = getToken();
        System.out.println("My Tokenis " + access_token);
        HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
        headers.setAccept(Collections.singletonList(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON));
        headers.add("Authorization", "Bearer " + access_token);
        RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
        ResponseEntity<String> response = restTemplate.exchange(
                "https://management.azure.com/providers/Microsoft.Management/managementGroups?api-version=2020-05-01",
                HttpMethod.GET, new HttpEntity<>("parameters", headers), String.class);
        return response.getBody();
    }
```

**Output:**

In my case, I'm retrieving management groups using spring boot with the above given code.

[image]

**References:**

*Refer my github [repository](https://github.com/PravallikaKothaveerannagari/Retrieve_Management_groups) for complete code.*